# How I can solve this differential equation: $y'''(x)+ax\,y(x)=0$?

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, mathematical-physics, hypergeometric-function

I have done some attempts to solve the following ODE:
$$y'''(x)+ax\,y(x)=0\,,$$ with $a >0$.

I put $y(x)= e^{rx}$, with $r$ is an arbitrary  real number, then $y'''=r^3 e^{rx}$, by substitution in the titled equation I got: $r^3 e^x +a x e^{rx}=0$ implies $ e^{rx}(r^3+a x)=0$ implies $x=\frac{-a}{r^3}$ this yield to $y(x)= \exp(\frac{-a x}{r^3})$, But I didn't got the same result using wolfram alpha as shown [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%27%27%27%2Baxy%3D0&wal=header) , The result were given by Generalized hypergeometric function, Any help?

Comment: look i have tried to fix your attempt, if you see any error you can fix it again

Comment: thank you so much

Comment: This is not a linear differential equation with constant coefficients, so you can't use the characteristic equation to solve it.

Comment: One way to tackle this equation is to use series method, since this type of ODE allows the solution to be written in a taylor series converging in real line. Such types of methods are allowed or are you limited to using an analytical method of solution?

Comment: i need an analytical method if you can help me.

Comment: Yeah Wolfram gives a long, nasty answer involving hypergeometric functions. The method to get to that answer probably is going to be gross. Maybe Laplace Transforms could get you there? A power series solution really is probably your best bet other than the hypergeometric mess

Comment: You would need $r^3 + a x = 0$ to hold for all $x$. The Frobenius method generalizes to higher-order equations. If $y = \sum_{k \geq 0} c_k x^k$, then $c_{k + 4} = -a c_k/((k + 2) (k + 3) (k + 4))$ and $c_3 = 0$. This gives three linearly independent solutions.